# Using Gradle, how can I ensure that a file exists at a certain location?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am starting to use Gradle for an Android application.  I would like the build to fail if the developer fails to create a file at a specific location such as `./src/res/values/specialfile.xml`

A bit of [searching](http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Copy-file-into-WEB-INF-fail-if-not-exists-td5709846.html) led me to believe that a `.doFirst` would work

```
android.doFirst { 
    assert file("./src/res/values/specialfile.txt").exists() 
}
```

However, Gradle says  *"unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'doFirst()'!"*

What can I do to assert a file's existence?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

doFirst only exists on tasks object. `android` is not a task.

If would want this test to always be done even if the developer doesn't try to build (for example when running the `tasks` task), you should simply put in your `build.gradle`

```
assert file("./src/res/values/specialfile.txt").exists()
```

However this is really not recommended as this would be executed even for non build tasks, or even when the model is built for IDE integration.

There is a task called `preBuild` that is executed before anything in the android build, so you can hook your test to it, either through another task or through `doFirst`:

```
preBuild.doFirst { 
    assert file("./src/res/values/specialfile.txt").exists() 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I used the `preBuild.doFirst` way and it works.  I am doing it to ensure that the developer creates a file containing various API keys, each developer will have their own which they must fill in.  This is the best way that I could come up with but if after hearing this you have a better way, do share.

Comment: For posterity and/or contexts where there is no `preBuild` task (perhaps this has been removed or is android specific), you can do exactly the same thing w/ `build`.

Answer (score 4):

One may want to check in a module `build.gradle` ...

- *below* the `plugins` configuration block
- *above* the `android` configuration block

eg. in order to determine which Gradle plugins to apply:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
}

def json_google = "src/google-services.json";
if (project.file(json_google).exists()) {
    println "found: ${project.file(json_google)}"
    apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
    apply plugin: "com.google.firebase.crashlytics"
    ...
} else {
    def message = "missing: ${project.file(json_google)}"
    // throw new GradleException(message)
    println message
}

android { ... }
```

`rootProject.file()` and `project.file()` might be more convenient than `file()` (it depends). Using `assert` seems a bit harsh - but then one has to take care that it will not crash elsewhere.

My projects usually have a few optional config files, which the environment may or may not provide, because not every product flavor may require the same set of plugins & config files.